# Usage of "be" infinitive form with no modal verb

Tags: grammar, infinitives

Could someone please explain why the verb "be" in the sentence below is in infinitive form? I was confused as there is no modal verb preceding the "be". Is it some sort of technique used in literature to emphasize or convey some message?

**The lady said "Though that desired at last *be* come, because I go alone how gladly would I live!".**

Comment: The language is very old - maybe pre-19th c. It is not an infinitive, it is a subjunctive. (It is also an old use of the verb "to be" to form the perfect tense.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear and concise answer.